# How I can remove the link breaks or tabs in dynamically generated paths?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Can anyone please tell me that how I can remove the line breaks in dynamically generated paths?

See example given below;

I'm using this code to generate the dynamic paths in href.

```
$text = trim('<?php echo SITE_ROOT; ?>' . '/') . $currentProjectName . $defaultCssDir . $filename;
```

Output in HTML:

```
<link href="<?php echo SITE_ROOT; ?>
                /sample-2/public/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But I want output in this style:

```
<link href="<?php echo SITE_ROOT; ?>/sample-2/public/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks in advance! 
Smac

Comment: Why you want to output `<?php` tags? Or you mean `http://example.com/sample-2...`?

Comment: Try string output with double quotes (") instead of single ('). There is a difference

Comment: Actually I'm trying to print php code in path. I also have tried with double quotes but still same problem. Can you please help a bit more?

Comment: you might need to trim `$currentProjectName` and `$defaultCssDir` too

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you `print` or `echo` your `$text` variable:

```
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $text);
```